# What is the most effective way to use header files

Tags: c, file, header

So currently in my programming I now have a fairly large range of functions I have created and stored in separate C files that I use quite frequently from project to project.

My question is what is the simplest, most effective way to implement them into other projects? Currently I just make a header file for each new project that has the function prototypes for all the custom functions I want to use.

I then have every C file in the project include this "master" header. In this header I also include header files that each C file utilizes, so every C file has one header; let's just call it `master.h`.

I feel like I am doing this completely wrong. Should I be making header files for each C file and including them into a master header file? or should I just create header files per C file and include them as needed? If I do that how will everything still be linked together?

What is the best way to go about using header files in projects?

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for SO because its answer is subjective rather than objective. As to `If I do that how will everything still be linked together?` -- your linker doesn't look at your header files, only the objects created by the compiler. As long as your header file contents satisfy the compiler, and you link in all the right pieces, the link will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Do not have a header file including other header files. Let the `.c` file do that - makes compilation quicker.
2. Use forward declarations. Makes recompilation quicker as it does not need to open up other files and if any simple change the `make` command will spend ages compiling lots of stuff.
3. Group functions together in both a header file and the corresponding `.c` file if they logically fit together. For static libraries the linker picks out the appropriate bits. For dynamic libraries they are loaded at run time (hence can be used by other binaries) if not currently in memory.
4. Do not have a `master.h`. Just make libraries contain functions that are related (e.g. math function, input/output functions etc). The various projects can pick 'n' chose what they require.

Comment: Point 3 is not correct. The static linker won't pick out the appropriate bits from the object file. It is more likely to throw in the whole object file. You should have one source file per function.

Comment: Point 1 is flat-out bad advice.  Headers should manage their own dependencies, period.  I've wasted more afternoons than I care to count trying to arrange headers in *just* the right order to get something to build.  What's really fun is when someone drops a new version of a header that changes those dependencies, meaning I get to do that exercise *again*.  The tradeoff in build times is *not that bad* compared to development time wasted.

Comment: With regard to #1:  If "stack.h" includes a struct from "object.h", does that still apply? Or do you feel the c file that uses "stack.h" should also have to include "object.h".

Comment: Point 1 - Edited. I Should have wrote that it should be avoided.

Comment: Now I do agree that a "master" header file that includes *everything* is also a bad idea.

Comment: @scooter - Put that struct in a separate file and avoid dependencies.

Comment: @John Bode - Just think that header files should be able to be compiled on there own with as few `#includes` as possible. But by that I do deferentiate between the standard ones (i.e. `#include <...>`) and `#include "...>"`

Comment: @TomTanner Your advice on one file per function seems bad as it is. This makes very little sense no matter how you twist it. Regarding static linking, could you perhaps supply a source for "the likely" behaviour that you're suggesting?

Comment: @HonkyTonk - pretty much any linker works like this. Solaris for one, aix unless you use special options for the compiler, to name but two. You'll find the entire C library on a statically linked system is written in this way

Comment: @Ed Heal  In my hypothetical, the struct was already in a separate file.

Comment: @HonkyTonk  If the linker didn't include the entire object file, it would have to examine the object code and determine where the used function started and ended, and whether or not the function accessed a static variable defined outside of it inside the object file. A large task for a product that has obvious warts given some of it's error messages and the sometimes required duplicate -l parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against having a `master.h` file, as your whole project ends up being too coupled. Every time you change `master.h` all your source files need to be recompiled, which significantly slows down the build process. Instead, try to create `.h` files with related functions. The C library is a good inspiration for this: `stdlib.h`, `math.h` etc.

In order to use these headers, you should include them in each `.c`, just like you would with the standard C headers:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

As for linking, this is a totally different subject. If most of your functions are inlined, you do not have to worry about linking. Otherwise, you should define them in `.c` files which are named similarly to your headers (e.g., `utils.c` for `utils.h` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a header file for all the `.c` files. Group the similar functions in a `.c` file. Dont forget to add header guard in each header files.

For example consider a header file `one.h`, it should contain the below header guards.

```
#ifndef ONE_H
#define ONE_H

//give your function prototypes here.

#endif //ONE_H
```

Header guard will be useful to avoid double includes.